# Ajax dentro de "each" elementos html jquery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, bucles, each

Quiero realizar un ajax dentro de each que hago sobre elementos que tengo en html.

```
$(".boton-estado").each(function(){
 elementoActual= $(this);
 elementoId = elementoActual.attr("id")
 $.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
    const productos = JSON.parse(response);
    productos.forEach(producto => {
      console.log(elementoId)
    });      
  }
 });
});
```

el `console.log(elementoId)` me imprime solo el último elementoId.

Cual es el problema? es como que el each(sobre los elementos) lo hace antes de hacer el ajax

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Aquí `$(".boton-estado").each(function(){` no se escucha ningún evento, simplemente busca los elementos con la clase `boton-estado`  y lanza ese bloque de código ¿te refieres a eso? ¿qué debe ocurrir para que la petición Ajax se lance?

Comment: $(".boton-estado").each(function(){} recorro los elementos con esa clase. Luego en cuada vuelta del each, hago la petición ajax.

Comment: Correcto, pero **las peticiones Ajax son asíncronas**, significa que no tienes control exacto del tiempo en que cada una de ellas responderá. Es más, si lanzas `N` peticiones en un orden determinado, las respuestas pueden ser incluso dislocadas (por ejemplo, la petición 3 puede responder antes que la petición 1), todo depende de muchos factores. No sé si tienes claro lo que significa asíncrono ¿?

Comment: Perfecto, si. Ahí pude corregir el error. Es como vos decís!